# Convergence of approximation of pseudo-inverse

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, pseudoinverse, inverse-problems

Let $X, Y$ be Hilbert spaces and $A\in L(X,Y)$ be a bounded linear map. Let $\{ R_t\}_t$ a family of functions $Y \rightarrow X$ and $\gamma: \mathbb{R}_+\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ with the property $$\sup\{||A^+g-R_{\gamma(\epsilon,z)}z||, g \in \text{domain}(A^+), ||g-z||\leq \epsilon\}=:h(\epsilon) \rightarrow 0$$

where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

> Is it then true that $A^+$ is continuous?

I would say yes, as if we take $g_n\rightarrow g$ in $\text{domain}(A^+)$, one can trivially write, for $\epsilon_n := ||g_n-g||$ $$||A^+g-A^+g_n||\leq ||A^+g-R_{\gamma(\epsilon_n,g_n)}g_n|| +||R_{\gamma(\epsilon_n,g_n)}g_n-A^+g_n||\\\leq h(\epsilon_n)+h(0)=h(\epsilon_n)\rightarrow0$$

Is this reasoning correct/is my claim correct?

Comment: $A^\dagger$ is bounded if and only if $R(A)$ is closed. This is Prop 2.4 in the book by Engl, Hanke, Neubauer.

Comment: @daw where am I using this fact?

Comment: Are $R_t :  Y \to X$ for each $t>0$? You seem to be taking $R_tz$ for $z \in Y$ (which is the domain of $A^{+}$) and subtracting it from $A^+g$, an element of $X$. Either way, you can also see [this resource](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82794791.pdf) , which seems to be useful. I feel like you are trying to bring $R_t$ close to $A$ in norm as $t$ increases, but there's no property about $R_t$ that I know, so I don't know why I should expect anything from $A$.

Comment: Correction : I made a mistake in the "in norm" part : I realize that $R_t$ may not be linear (it hasn't been mentioned), so they mayn't be in that particular subspace of operators where the norm can be applied.  Having said that, everything else still stands. I need to know something about $R_t$ to know something about $A$, I think.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I added a clarification on domains and codomains of $R_t$. I could even suppose $R_t$ continuous and pointwise convergent to $A^+$ on the domain of $A^+$, but I feel that this is superfluous.

Comment: What is your definition of Moore-Penrose inverse?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this approach using these kind of regularizing functions $R_t$?

Comment: @daw Least squares solution of minimum norm

Comment: @daw An Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of Inverse Problem, Kirsch, A., chapter  2, for instance. If you are familiar with german, also Keine Probleme mit Inversen Problemen, or 
Inverse.

Comment: @warm_fish Thank you very much! I'll read up and let you know if I get something interesting. It also seems to me that $h(0)$ is a bit of an oddity because $h$ looks like it depends on $\epsilon_n$ which we assume is strictly positive . I think you can just replace it by $h(\epsilon_n)$ itself, as daw says, and then you'd be done anyway.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon You are correct, let's replace $h(0)$ by $h(\epsilon_n)$

Comment: @warm_fish That should be good.

Comment: I think, the Moore-Penrose inverse does not satisfy your assumption in general.  If it is satisfied, then the inverse is continuous, as you demonstrated.

Comment: @daw The assumption of existence of such $R_t$? In case: yes, this is one of the reason why people go to smoothing techniques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, however the definition of the regularizing family is different than usually. I found the following definition in the book by Rieder [Keine Probleme mit inversen Problemen (in German)] Def 3.1.1:
$$
\forall g\in D(A^\dagger): \ \sup\{ \|A^\dagger g - R_{(\cdots)}(z): \ \|z-g\|_Y\le \epsilon\} \to 0 \quad \text{ for } \epsilon\to 0.
$$
You wrote
$$\ \sup\{ \|A^\dagger g - R_{(\cdots)}(z): \ g\in D(A^\dagger),\ \|z-g\|_Y\le \epsilon\} \to 0 \quad \text{ for } \epsilon\to 0,
$$
which is much stronger, as it implies continuity of $A^\dagger$.